# how to change font dynamically in table cell using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fonts

On a user event I am dynamically building a html table in a pop window in my code I have the following line that builds the table row cells:

```
$("<td BGCOLOR='#F9ED6E'><font color='#ff2500'></font></td>").text(object[property]).appendTo(row);
```

This does change the background color but it does not change the font color is there a way to rewrite this statement above to allow also changing the font color? I suspect somehow that .text(object[property] needs to go after the "font color='#ff2500'" part but I'm not certain how to do that?

Comment: well. you have no text between your font tags. so how do you know the font color hasn't changed?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out how do I change the line of code above to put the text between the font tags?

Comment: so you're trying to create a new cell with javascript with dynamic colors and text, and add it to the element "row"?

Comment: Tyler - yes. Is there an easy way to modify my line above to put the text "(.text(object[property]) between the font tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my jQuery isn't so great. So I can show you a way to do it with plain old javascript.  This would be considered kind of a dirty way to do it. But it should work just fine.

```
row.innerHTML = "<td BGCOLOR='#F9ED6E'><font color='#ff2500'>" + object[property] + "</font></td>";
```

Now I'm sure someone could tell you a good way to do a similar thing in jQuery. Also, if I were doing this "more properly" I'd create actual DOM elements in js and append them to the row. But I thought this might be easier to understand as it uses the same sort of technique you were using. And it'll work just fine.

**UPDATE: The Proper Method**
But still vanilla javascript

```
var eCell;
eCell = document.createElement("td");
eCell.style.backgroundColor = "#F9ED6E";
eCell.style.color = "#ff2500";
eCell.innerHTML = object[property];

row.appendChild(eCell);
```

Comment: tyler - thanks I will give it a try using straight javascript hopefully someone will reply with how to do it with jquery? I'll also think about creating the DOM elements in js and append to row as you suggest. If I get it working with raw javascript per your example and nobody comes up with a jquery way I accept this as the answer. I check it has helpful for now.

Comment: @NealDavis - hope it helps. If you like, I've added some code to my example, gives an idea of the proper way to do it with plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be using CSS.

```
td {color:#fff}
```

Then you won't need to use a Font tag, and the text inside will be white.
By the way, I don't see you are typing anything inside the table.

Comment: Hi Hugo the ".text(object[property])" is the text that is put in the cell. I may have to resort to using a class and CSS I was hoping not to since depending on what is in .text(object[property]) I want to use different colors?

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use a class for all the styles and insert them as a property of the 'td'. Lets imagine that you have a div where you want to add those td elements you need to get that element and then add the td. Here is an example how you acomplish that. Is very simple but can give you and idea

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    /* Act on the event */
    $("#myDiv").append("<td class='background'></td>");
  });
});
```

Comment: Abraham - I may have to use as you suggest a class and CSS but was hoping to be able to do it with the font tag since cells can have different colors depending on what is in .text(object[property])